# SSL connect error in R jsonlite package

Tags: r, ssl, jsonlite

I am trying to load data from website that are in JSON format so I am using `jsonlite` R package and `fromJSON` function. I receive an error as below

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(URL) -> x
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : SSL connect error
```

Does anyone know what this error mean and how to (probably) configure SSL to makethis function work?

Comment: Just hit this myself. If I paste the URL into a browser it works fine. Even in a fresh incognito wndow

Answer (score 0):

Update to version 1.2 of the `jsonlite` package. This was a bug fixed by the new version of the package. Read more at https://ropensci.org/blog/technotes/2017/01/04/jsonlite-12.